# wifstream equivalent to _wfopen's "mode" parameter?

Tags: c++, unicode, file-io

I'm having troubles opening a Unicode file in C++ using fstreams instead of the older FILE-based file handling functions. When opening a file using _wfopen, I can specify a mode to tell it what character encoding to use. Eg:

```
_wfopen_s(&file, fileName, unicode ? L"r+, ccs=UTF-16LE" : L"r+" );
```

This works fine. When using wifstream though, I get both the byte-order mark at the beginning of the file, and the rest of the file appears in memory interlaced with 0x00. Clearly it's just reading in each character as a byte.

My question is: is there any equivalent to the 'mode' parameter above for use with fstreams? It's not terrible if there isn't, I just prefer the syntax of streams over FILEs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting using a conversion facet for the stream.
Check the files [codecvt.h](http://www.farmanager.com/svn/branches/plugins/ftp/civilis/utils/codecvt.h) and [codecvt.cpp](http://www.farmanager.com/svn/branches/plugins/ftp/civilis/utils/codecvt.cpp) as an example.